# How to make a generic parameter optional in interface in java?

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have an interface which has 2 generic parameters.But abstract method inside sometimes is needed to accept only 1 generic parameter.How can i make that happen ? The way i see it i can't make the generics optional and also if i write an overloaded method inside the interface it will be unnecessarily implemented in some java classes(which will be implementing that interface) where it's not needed. Now i am passing the parameterized which is needed twice both in the class header while implementing the interface and also inside a function,since i compulsorily have to pass 2 arguments.I am stuck.Any direction ?

```
public interface ITaskPermissionHandler<T, V> {

    String getType();

    boolean hasPermission(T clazz, UserRef user, String type, V clazz1);
}

public class CreateTaskPermission implements ITaskPermissionHandler<Task,Task> {

    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return TaskConstants.CREATE_TASK;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Task task, UserRef user, String type, Task      task1) {
        return type.equalsIgnoreCase(TaskConstants.CREATE_TASK);
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like those generics are winning you anything, anyway.  Why do you have them?  I'm hesitant to leave an answer until I actually understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I don't see the problem here. This is a common method how to do it. Just look at a `Map` with `String`s as keys and values. Then you'd write `Map<String, String>` as well.

Comment: @QBrute:  Yes, but those actually map to something meaningful.  The OP's code doesn't even make use of those generic types *anywhere*.

Answer (score 2):

Your method takes 4 parameters. You cannot suddenly make it take 3.

If you want a method with 3 parameters, then it is a different method (overload), and you need a different interface with that method.

You can however do what the [`java.util.function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) interfaces do, and extend the interface with a simpler version, like how [`BinaryOperator<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html) extends [`BiFunction<T,T,T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html).

Like one of these ways:

```java
interface ISimplePermissionHandler<T> extends ITaskPermissionHandler<T, T> {
    default boolean hasPermission(T clazz, UserRef user, String type) {
        return hasPermission(clazz, user, type, clazz);
    }
}   
class CreateTaskPermission implements ISimplePermissionHandler<Task> {
    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return TaskConstants.CREATE_TASK;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Task task, UserRef user, String type, Task task1) {
        return type.equalsIgnoreCase(TaskConstants.CREATE_TASK);
    }
}
```

```java
interface ISimplePermissionHandler<T> extends ITaskPermissionHandler<T, T> {
    @Override
    default boolean hasPermission(T clazz, UserRef user, String type, T clazz1) {
        return hasPermission(clazz, user, type);
    }
    boolean hasPermission(T clazz, UserRef user, String type);
}   
class CreateTaskPermission implements ISimplePermissionHandler<Task> {
    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return TaskConstants.CREATE_TASK;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Task task, UserRef user, String type) {
        return type.equalsIgnoreCase(TaskConstants.CREATE_TASK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code changes ITaskPermissionHandler<T, V> (OP's code) to ITaskPermissionHandler<T, T> (your code)...Is this intentional?

Comment: @deckeresq I did not *change* `ITaskPermissionHandler`. I'm *using* it, exactly as defined in the question.

Comment: Ah, sorry, it seems I misread your code. Thanks for the clarification!